# TypeScript and GraphQL jwt refresh token and blacklist

Tags: typescript, graphql, jwt

Hello I did the following for my auth and refresh jwt:

**my entity**

```
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => Int)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column("text")
  login: string;

  @Column("text")
  password: string;

  @Column("int", { default: 0 })
  tokenVersion: number;
}
```

**Make refresh and auth token**

```
export const createAccessToken = (user: User) => {
  return sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET!, {
    expiresIn: "15m"
  });
};

export const createRefreshToken = (user: User) => {
  return sign(
    { userId: user.id, tokenVersion: user.tokenVersion },
    process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET!,
    {
      expiresIn: "120m"
    }
  );
};
```

**My Middleware**:

```
export const isAuth: MiddlewareFn<MyContext> = ({ context }, next) => {
  const authorization = context.req.headers["authorization"];

  if (!authorization) {
    throw new Error("not authenticated");
  }

  try {
    const token = authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const payload = verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET!);
    context.payload = payload as any;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error("not authenticated");
  }

  return next();
};
```

How do I send my token to the client by cookies

```
export const sendRefreshToken = (res: Response, token: string) => {
  res.cookie("jid", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: "/refresh_token"
  });
};
```

**My route to receive a refresh token:**

```
  app.post("/refresh_token", async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jid;
    if (!token) {
      return res.send({ ok: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    let payload: any = null;
    try {
      payload = verify(token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET!);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.send({ ok: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ id: payload.userId });

    if (!user) {
      return res.send({ ok: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    if (user.tokenVersion !== payload.tokenVersion) {
      return res.send({ ok: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    sendRefreshToken(res, createRefreshToken(user));

    return res.send({ ok: true, accessToken: createAccessToken(user) });
  });
```

**my resolver to login and revoke Refresh Tokens For User**

```
@Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async revokeRefreshTokensForUser(@Arg("userId", () => Int) userId: number) {
    await getConnection()
      .getRepository(User)
      .increment({ id: userId }, "tokenVersion", 1);

    return true;
  }

  @Mutation(() => LoginResponse)
  async login(
    @Arg("login") login: string,
    @Arg("password") password: string,
    @Ctx() { res }: MyContext
  ): Promise<LoginResponse> {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { login } });

    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("could not find user");
    }

    const valid = await compare(password, user.password);

    if (!valid) {
      throw new Error("bad password");
    }

    // login successful

    sendRefreshToken(res, createRefreshToken(user));

    return {
      accessToken: createAccessToken(user),
      user
    };
  }
```

Hello i would like to know how i could instead use a field in my user table create a blacklist for jwt, i don't know if i can improve the code
I know that sending via cookies there is a risk of xss and csrf, I don't know how to use the csurf library to avoid this:

```
  // app.use(require("csurf")({ cookie: true }));
  // app.use(csrf());
```

Comment: You could return it as a normal graphql query and then set it as cookie in your front-end.

Comment: could you show me an example? how could I do that?

Comment: storing plain passwords is a risk, detailed errors are a some risk, too